# Xamarin FirebaseAnalytics.GetInstance(this) java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.android.gms.common.util.zzh.zzyv

Tags: android, xamarin.android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging for notifications in my Xamarin Android app. This seems to be working fine. When I add Xamarin.Firebase.Analytics, I get the following exception:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.android.gms.common.util.zzh.zzyv

when I call

```
FirebaseAnalytics.GetInstance(this);
```

I'm using version 42.1001.0 for all Xamarin.Firebase.*** packages.
All I've been able to find has been about different version numbers of the different Firebase packages.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GMS packages (com.android.google.gms.*) conflict with firebase packages.

You can resolve it by by using the latest android target API

Comment: I have the Compile using Android version set to Use Latest Platform (Android 7.1 (Nougat))

Comment: In the manifest settings I have Minimum Android version set to Android 4.4 (API Level 19 - Kit Kat) and Target Android version set to Use Compile using SDK version